# spark - filter within map

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am trying to filter inside map function. Basically the way I'll do that in classic map-reduce is mapper wont write anything to context when filter criteria meet. How can I achieve similar with spark? I can't seem to return null from map function as it fails in shuffle step. I can either use filter function but it seems unnecessary iteration of data set while I can perform same task during map. I can also try to output null with dummy key but thats a bad workaround.

Comment: could you add sample code illustrating the issue?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are few options:

`rdd.flatMap`: `rdd.flatMap` will flatten a `Traversable` collection into the RDD. To pick elements, you'll typically return an `Option` as result of the transformation.

```
rdd.flatMap(elem => if (filter(elem)) Some(f(elem)) else None)
```

`rdd.collect(pf: PartialFunction)` allows you to provide a partial function that can filter and transform elements from the original RDD. You can use all power of pattern matching with this method.

```
rdd.collect{case t if (cond(t)) => f(t)}
rdd.collect{case t:GivenType => f(t)}
```

As Dean Wampler mentions in the comments, `rdd.map(f(_)).filter(cond(_))` might be as good and even faster than the other more 'terse' options mentioned above.

Where `f` is a transformation (or map) function.

Comment: If you use `...filter().map()`, they will be executed in the same task for each partition, analogous to chaining "mappers" in MapReduce. This might even be faster than a single `flatMap` or `collect`, depending on how many temporary objects get allocated, then quickly garbage collected.

Comment: @DeanWampler I knew about the pipelining but it's good to know that `filter().map()` might be faster than `flatmap` or `collect`... we replaced many `map().filter()` by `collect()` b/c reads better but will need to check perf. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks.For now, "chain of map" way is not hindering me.  I'll look into equivalent flatmap suggestion in Java 8 later when I look into perf

Comment: @maasg flatmap proved useful to me both for code simplicity and performance. I removed spark sql layer as well and used flatmap function to do both filtering and mapping.

Comment: @maasg - I may be wrong, but looking at the flatMap source, seems like flatMap is a single iteration where are filter.map seems like two iterations thru each partition -  `def flatMap[U : Encoder](func: T => TraversableOnce[U]): Dataset[U] =    mapPartitions(_.flatMap(func))`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try `map_filter(col, lambda-function)`
Here are the docs: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.map_filter.html#pyspark.sql.functions.map_filter