# Scala Spark filter inside map

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to efficiently filter an RDD while mapping it. Is that possible?

Here is pseudocode for what I want to do:

```
for element in rdd:
    val opt = f(element)
    if (opt.nonEmpty) add_pair(opt.get, element)
```

Here is a hacky way to implement the pseudocode in Scala Spark:

```
rdd.map(element => (
    f(element).getOrElse(99),
    element
)).filter(tuple => tuple._1 != 99)
```

I wasn't able to find clean syntax to do this, so I first mapped all elements, and then filtered out the ones I don't want. Note that potentially expensive call `f(element)` is only computed once. If I were to filter elements before mapping (which would look more clean), then I would end up calling `f` twice, which is inefficient.

Please do not flag this as a duplicate. While there are similar questions, none of them actually answer this question. For example, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28843591/spark-filter-within-map) potential duplicate would call `f` twice, which is inefficient, and therefore does not answer this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just use `flatMap`:

```
//let's say your f returns Some(x*2) for even number and None for odd
def f(n: Int): Option[Int] = if (n % 2) Some(n*2) else None 

val rdd = sc.parallelize(List(1,2,3,4))
rdd.flatMap(f) // 4,8

// rdd.flatMap(f) or rdd.flatMap(f(_)) or rdd.flatMap(e => f(e))
```

And if you need to pass tuple further and filter, then just use nested `map`:

```
rdd.flatMap(e => f(e).map((_,e))) //(4,2),(8,4)
```

Comment: Oh that's clever, `None` is flattened like an empty list. I was able to extend this answer into the case in OP where we need to map to (k,v) tuples (rather than simply values as is done here), and do it without modifying `f`.

Comment: I understood, that you only create tuple for filtering. Check out my edit for creating tuple and filtering in one step.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `mapPartitions` to do the filter along with your expensive calculation.

```
rdd.mapPartitions( elements => 
  elements
      .map(element => (f(element),element))
      .filter(tuple => tuple._1.isDefined)
)
```

Note that in this code, the `filter` is the native scala collection method, not the Spark RDD filter.

Alternatively, you can also `flatMap` the result of your function

```
rdd.flatMap(element => f(element).map(result => (result,element)))
```

Comment: If you prefer, you can filter directly on the option (code updated) but I'm not sure I really understand what you're trying to achieve. Also `flatMap` works fine too as per the other answer.

Comment: This is better than my "99" hack! To clarify, I'm trying to achieve the behavior of the pseudocode in OP: do one pass over the collection and add tuples corresponding to elements which pass f(element), without ugly hacks. This is almost there. It's clean, but it's doing 2 passes instead of 1 pass. Although I suppose this 1-pass vs. 2-pass thing doesn't matter too much.

Comment: Ok, so you want a single collection transform, that's a `flatMap` then. I'll add it as a second option

Comment: I'm not sure what is supposed to happen when we try to flatten a `(None,element)` tuple? I thought the collection that we flatten is supposed to contain items like `None` and `Some((result,element))`, not items like `(None,element)`?

Comment: I believe I got it working by modifying Krzysztof's answer: https://pastebin.com/1y1BtfWf

Comment: In the second version, if element is a type `A` and f(element) returns an `Option[B]`, `result` is of type `B` and the output of `f(element).map(...)` is of type `Option[(B,A)]` so flatMap works OK. Actually my second answer and Krysztof's second one are identical (I used explicit named variables, he used the more scala-ish implicit notation). Accept his answer :)

Comment: Looking at your pastebin code, if you want, you can shorten the vectorPostings function to simply: `scored.flatMap(tuple => tuple._1.tags.map(langs.indexOf).filter(_ >= 0).map((_ * langSpread,tuple._2)))`